# Can not download pdf file using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf

I have an issue while downloading some document from my webpage using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<tr>
<th>Document</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="sup in viewSupplierData">
<td valign="middle" align="center"><a href="upload/{{sup.company_reg_docs}}" target="_self" alt="View/Download" title="View/Download"><img src="img/download_icon.jpg" name="pro" border="0" style="border:#808080 1px solid;"  /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Here i am setting the document link dynamically.For any `.docx` file its downloading but in case of any `pdf` related file its opening in new page not donloading.Here i need all files should download directly.Please help me.

Comment: In many cases, that's due to browser preferences (i.e. always open, always download, never open, etc) so you might have different reactions in different browsers and their user settings.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Browser solution, all files (pdf, jpg, docx, etc.) will be downloaded (Chrome, Firefox, IE). I am using it and it works like charm.

```
$window.open(URL_WHERE_YOU_GET_THE_FILE(BINARY), '_blank');
```

You also have to set some things on your response in your backend (Java example):

```
res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
res.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
```